# SecurityError in canavs.toDataUrl() when i use CSS backgrounds in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, safari, html2canvas

> Here is the code which i used for html2canvas , to convert canvas to dataURI . 
>   It works fine for chrome , firefox , IE  but throws an Security Error in Safari .

[image]

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('widgetElemet'), {
            logging: true,
            profile: true,
            useCORS: true,
            allowTaint: true,
        }).then(function(canvas) {
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();


            var param = {
                to: emailToArray.validEmails,
                cc: emailCCArray.validEmails,
                bcc: emailBccArray.validEmails,
                emailid: UserDetails.email,
                subject: emailSubject,
                message: emailMessage,
                ImageDataURI: dataURL
            }

            this.postScreenShot(param)
        }.bind(this));
```

> css class which i have used is

```
content: '';
display: block;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
/*background: url('../../content/images/sliderRight.png') no-repeat;*/
background: url('../../content/images/Right_Arrow_Active.png') no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
margin: 0px 6px;
```

Comment: You are sure it comes from this background-image? Also why set `allowTaint` if at the end you'll call `toDataURL`?

Comment: i think yes it comes from background image beacuse in other page where i have used image in <img> tag , it works fine .